# Nodejs build *.apk

Tags: android, linux, node.js, cmd, child-process

I need to build *.apk programatically when nodejs gets request. I already have Android project I need just to run process that generate *.apk file. I need solution for windows and linux, may be someone knows how to do it?

Comment: dev team from google made a good job: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Ok thanks, that's good, but how to run it on linux and windows from node server?

Comment: I am sure u are able to execute shell commands via a node.js script